# unable to read a csv from my computer in python (repl-it and aws cloud9)

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have no idea why, but I can't read a csv file from my computer using python. i've tried on both the AWS Cloud9 environment and in repl-it, but I always get a file not found error. here are all the ways i've tried below:

```
import pandas as pd   
import csv 

"""Import the PopChange.csv into a DataFrame for analysis."""
# Method 1
#df = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\cplun\Desktop\UMUC\SDEV_300\Week_5\PopChange.csv')

# Method 2
#df = pd.read_csv (r'C:\\Users\\cplun\\Desktop\\UMUC\\SDEV_300\\Week_5\\PopChange.csv')

# Method 3
#df = pd.read_csv ('C:\Users\cplun\Desktop\UMUC\SDEV_300\Week_5\PopChange.csv')

# Method 4
#df = pd.read_csv ('C:\\Users\\cplun\\Desktop\\UMUC\\SDEV_300\\Week_5\\PopChange.csv')

# Method 5
#df = pd.read_csv ("C:\\Users\\cplun\\Desktop\\UMUC\\SDEV_300\\Week_5\\PopChange.csv")

# Method 6
#df = pd.read_csv ("C:/Users/cplun/Desktop/UMUC/SDEV_300/Week_5/PopChange.csv")

# Method 7
#df = pd.read_csv ("C://Users//cplun//Desktop//UMUC//SDEV_300//Week_5//PopChange.csv")

# Method 7
#df = pd.read_csv ('C://Users//cplun//Desktop//UMUC//SDEV_300//Week_5//PopChange.csv')

# Method 8
#df = pd.read_csv ('C:/Users/cplun/Desktop/UMUC/SDEV_300/Week_5/PopChange.csv')

# Method 9
#df = pd.read_csv (r'C://Users//cplun//Desktop//UMUC//SDEV_300//Week_5//PopChange.csv')

# Method 10
df = pd.read_csv (r'C:/Users/cplun/Desktop/UMUC/SDEV_300/Week_5/PopChange.csv')


print (df)
```

I'm convinced I have the directory correct as it started as a copy and paste from the address bar in file explorer. likewise, the file name is exactly as written. I have no idea why it won't work!

Thanks,

Chuck

Comment: can you run `!ls` in a cell and provide what output do you get with it.

Comment: Himanshu, here it is in the Cloud9 terminal: vocstartsoft:~/environment $ !ls
bash: !ls: event not found
vocstartsoft:~/environment $

Comment: this is the complete error when trying to access the file in my Cloud9 directory: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/environment/Week_5_Project/DataAnalysisApplication.py", line 22, in <module>
    pop_change = pd.read_csv('PopChange.csv')
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 448, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 880, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1114, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1891, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 374, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 674, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File PopChange.csv does not exist: 'PopChange.csv'


Process exited with code: 0